# Custom Inbound channel adapter to invoke a Pojo service

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I need to start/stop an Ftp flow depending on the size of the incoming folder.
I have a service that verifies the folder size:

```
@Service
public class IncomingFolderChecker  {

  private static final int MAX_ALLOWED_SIZE = 2000000;

  @Value("${sftp.incoming}")
  private String incomingDir;

  @Autowired
  private MessageChannel controlChannel;

  public void checkFolderSize() {
    if (FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory(new File(this.incomingDir)) > MAX_ALLOWED_SIZE) {
      controlChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("@sftpInboundAdapter.stop()")); // typo: was 'start()'
    } else {
      controlChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("@sftpInboundAdapter.start()"));
    }
  }
}
```

I know that the control bus allows to do this.
But that's all I know about Spring Integration.
How can I hook this up using Java-DSL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all both your branches of the condition uses the same `start()` command. I guess one of them should be `stop()`. You code is correct as far as a `controlChannel` is an input channel for the Control Bus component. To do that with Java DSL you only need such a simple bean:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow controlBusFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("controlChannel")
                .controlBus()
                .get();
    }
```

If that's not a question, please clarify.

**UPDATE**

Everything together with the Spring Integration style and its Java DSL:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow controlSftpInboundAdapter(@Value("${sftp.incoming}") String incomingDir) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(() -> FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory(new File(incomingDir)) > MAX_ALLOWED_SIZE,
                        e -> e.poller(pollerFactory -> pollerFactory.fixedDelay(1000)))
                .<Boolean, String>transform(p -> "@sftpInboundAdapter." + (p ? "start()" : "stop()"))
                .controlBus()
                .get();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Artem Bilan ! Could you tell me how to connect the IncomingFolderChecker bean to a flow so that it can be polled every few seconds ? I am trying to hook it up as an incoming channel adapter.

Comment: First of all you need to understand that an Inbound Channel Adapter is a source of messages for the downstream flow. Therefore your source definitely has to provide some data each time it is going to be polled. Your `IncomingFolderChecker` doesn't fit for the `MessageSource` contract - `void` return type. You may consider just to mark your `checkFolderSize()` with the `@Scheduled` instead of reworking component for the `MessageSource` contract: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled

Comment: Thanks @Artem Bilan for your time. The @ Scheduled solution is really simple and that fixes my problem. Could you also provide a Spring Integration solution  if I change checkFolderSize() to return, say a boolean ?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Artem Bilan for the 2 solutions!